# What does {...} as a part of a function call mean?

Tags: uniswap, function

In the function `swapExactETHForTokens` of Uniswap is called like this:

```
 uniswap.swapExactETHForTokens{value: msg.value}(
            amountOut,
            path,
            msg.sender,
            deadline
        );
```

What does the part `{value: msg.value}` mean? Is this really correct syntasis at all? Meaning, the `{...}` itself in a function call.

And does the function not accept the `value` argument in the normal way, inside `(...)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how you can call a function and provide value to it.

The concept of *value* refers to Ethers sent along the call. The value is taken from the contract balance. You can't provide the *value* as a regular parameter inside `()` in Solidity if you want to send Ether, and not just some `uint` which happens to be called `value`.

Here's an example. If you call `demo` (remember to include value when calling the function, otherwise the contract doesn't have any value to forward), the `some` function call doesn't forward any value. But `other` call forwards *6 weis*. Note also that functions need to be declared `payable` in order to be able to receive value.

```
contract A {   
    function demo() public payable {
        B inst = new B();
        inst.some(5);
        inst.other{value: 6}();
    }
}
contract B {
    uint private _value;
    function some(uint value) public {
        _value = value;
    }
    function other() payable public {
    }
}
```

You can see the syntax for example here: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/control-structures.html#external-function-calls

Comment: `you really want to send Ether` -> how is "really want" different from merely "want"? Does the intensity of my desire affect syntax?

Comment: `and not just some uint which happens to be called value.` --> why not?

Comment: very well, edited my answer to include an example

Comment: You haven't explained "why"

Comment: Why you can't pass Ethers with just a function parameter value? Because, um, you can't. The language doesn't work like that.